# app.yaml handler login: admin option not effective on standard env python GAE app?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I was working on some security checks for my standard env python GAE app and I was surprised to see that the `login: admin` option appears to be non-effective.

I want to secure a portion of a request namespace to just the app itself, not external requests. The app sends these requests through a push task queue.

This is the respective handler configuration, which I checked in StackDriver to be the actual code that handled the particular request in question:

```
- url: /ci/ci_msg*  # external requests OK
  script: apartci.app
  secure: always

- url: /ci/.*       # internal requests only
  script: apartci.app
  secure: always
  login: admin
```

This is the handler code, hacked to log an error to check if the request actually hits the app code, also verified in StackDriver to be the actual handling code:

```
def post(self):
    logging.error('in post')
    self.handle_post()
```

I sent the external request to the exact same path that only the internal task queue requests should be accepted, using the Firefox HttpRequester add-on. The request body failed the additional checks in `self.handle_post()`, but that's irrelevant for this question.

The response I got in HttpRequester (rather irrelevant as well):

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>203 Non-Authoritative Information</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>203 Non-Authoritative Information</h1>
  <br /><br />
 </body>
</html>
```

I checked the app logs in StackDriver. To my surprise I found the `logging.error('in post')` app log from my handler's `post()` method attached to the request log, indicating that the request made it to my app:

[image]

For comparison - the log from the same request sent from the app itself (coincidentally just ~1 second before the external one and handled by the exact same instance - which contributed to my confusion):

[image]

My expectation was for the external request to not make it to the handler code, according to the login row in [Handlers element](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_element):

> **admin**
>
> As with **required**, performs [auth_fail_action](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_auth_fail_action) if the user is
>   not signed in. In addition, if the user is not an administrator for
>   the application, they are given an error message regardless of the
>   [auth_fail_action](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_auth_fail_action) setting. If the user is an administrator, the
>   handler proceeds.
>
> When a URL handler with a **login** setting other than **optional**
>   matches a URL, the handler first checks whether the user has signed in
>   to the application using its [authentication option](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/#Python_Authentication_options). If not, by
>   default, the user is redirected to the sign-in page. You can also use
>   [auth_fail_action](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_auth_fail_action) to configure the app to simply reject requests
>   for a handler from users who are not properly authenticated, instead
>   of redirecting the user to the sign-in page.
>
> Note: the **admin** login restriction is also satisfied for internal
>   requests for which App Engine sets appropriate **X-Appengine** special
>   headers. For example, **cron** scheduled tasks satisfy the **admin**
>   restriction, because App Engine sets an HTTP header
>   **X-AppEngine-Cron: true** on the respective requests. However, the requests would **not** satisfy the **required** login restriction,
>   because cron scheduled tasks are not run as any user.

So my question is why/how did the external request manage to hit the handler code? Am I missing something?

Comment: I tried POSTing to a task queue url using HttpRequester and got 302-ed to the Google Accounts login page, so this doesn't seem to be generic behaviour.

Comment: Yup, that's what I was expecting.  digging required...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mistery solved: apparently the Firefox HttpRequester add-on is smart enough to automatically pull the google credentials from Firefox and use them. The updated image in the question now has a pointer showing the username info I blacked out but didn't regard as a clue. Those credentials have admin permissions to the GAE app, which explains why that request made it to the handler code.

To confirm this theory I tried the same request but this time sent using `curl`:

> $ curl --request POST --data '{"task": "project_integrity_check_task",
>   "obj_id": 4841240159846400, "ci_proj": 4841240159846400, "obj_cls":
>   "Project"}' [url_redacted]

The response is indeed a `302` and the app error log is missing, indicating that this time the request didn't make it to the handler code, as expected:

[image]