# Changing app engine service account roles not effecting access

Tags: google-app-engine

My goal is to run a google app engine application with the minimal amount of access to resources it needs.  In my case the application will access the datastorage in the project (this is the golang example tutorial using the source code git checkout origin/part4-usingdatastore from https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-guestbook-go.git)

I did the following

- Create a new project, foobarproject3
- Created a new app in the project (using golang)
- In the project IAM/IAM noticed the 
  foobarproject3@appspot.gserviceaccount.com, assumed this is the service account, so changed it's role to just BigQuery User.  Notice that no Datastorage roles are configured (The UI forces me to provide access to something so I chose BQ)
- Followed the tutorial instructions for the using datastore golang app (guestbook application)and deployed the app.
- Opened the link to my app: https://foobarproject3.appspot.com/ It failed (this is great, this is what I expected, since the service account does not give the app permissions to read/write datastorage)
- Refreshed https://foobarproject3.appspot.com/ and it started to work

There is something basic that I'm not understanding about service account from app engine.  Isn't the app engine using these service account to access project resources?  Why is the app getting access to datastorage when the service account does not have a policy that would allow access to datastorage?

Answer (score 0):

"My goal is to run a google app engine application with the minimal amount of access to resources it needs."

This is dicey to unpack without more context. What is it that you're trying to achieve that goes beyond App Engine's default behavior?

My experience is that if one starts changing roles without understanding the basics, things go sideways (or South, or West, or Pear-shaped, depending on where you are). So I suspect you shot yourself in the foot in your third bullet.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the value of app engine service account.  I thought the service account could be used to enable or restrict the running app engine application's access to project resources.  But, after removing the datastorage policy from the service credentials the app engine application still had read and write access to datastorage.

Comment: "Projects resources" is broad. I've only needed to deal with service accounts when interacting with Google-provided APIs that aren't part of the standard App Engine set.

Answer (score 0):

When you access your app from the browser you are using your own user credentials, not the app's service account. And your user credentials *might* be exactly the app owner/admin ones, if you created the app using those credentials. See, for example, [app.yaml handler login: admin option not effective on standard env python GAE app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46823143/app-yaml-handler-login-admin-option-not-effective-on-standard-env-python-gae-ap)

Make sure you log out from the app, or try accessing the app from an incognito browser window or by using a dumb(er) utility to prevent accidental/undesired credential leaking.

The app's service account is for your app to identify itself when it's interacting with other services/apps. From [Understanding Service Accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts):

> A service account is a special type of Google account that belongs to
>   your application or a virtual machine (VM), instead of to an
>   individual end user. Your application [assumes the identity of the
>   service account to call Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#authorizingrequests), so that the users aren't
>   directly involved. A service account can have zero or more pairs of
>   service account keys, which are used to authenticate to Google.

Comment: I tried from a diff browser and from curl.   I'm trying to use service account  to restrict the access of the running app engine application.  Maybe I'm missing the point of the service account.