# Secure all URLs Security constraint is not working in App engine Standard java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm using App Engine standard environment. I want to make all url to access only admin.

Here is my `web.xml` but this one is not working for me I test it on local development.

```
<web-app>
 ......

<!-- Security -->
<security-role>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>admin</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

.....
</web-app>
```

I checked the documentation right here [Security and Authentication](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/webxml#Security_and_Authentication)

Can you please let me know why this one is not working for me. What I'm doing wrong ?

And second thing I want to ask is that If I protect all urls to access only admin can I still use cloud endpoint lib in Android can my app access endpoints or not without any login ?

I'm using `java8`

Comment: How are you testing it? I had a similar experience (w/ python) but it turned out admin auth was leaking into my test: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46823143/app-yaml-handler-login-admin-option-not-effective-on-standard-env-python-gae-ap

Comment: I opened the url (e.g task queue url) with logged in user and without login user it work for both. I want admin login can access this. I mean only developer gmail account not any other. But above code is not working for me, am i doing anything wrong

Comment: Can you try again with Chrome's incognito browser? That's to make sure there's no past credential / cookie somewhere authenticating it via your logged in account.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes your browser would keep your accounts logged it or at least keep cookies that could authenticate you. Try again with incognito and it should work. If you have the security setup and it doesn't work incognito, then it's likely an issue on our end that cannot be address over Stackoverflow. In which case, please file an issue with us with the [Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/#public_users), and we will be able to investigate into it, thanks.

Comment: Yes, I already try it with incognito mode. But have a same problem. URL even work in incognito mode.